# Why ul li items are vertically uneven

Tags: html, css

I have this simple HTML5 snippet to narrow down to a problem. The LI elements fail to line up. Why Item 1 is positioned lower than Item 2? I want them to be on the same level. Any help would be very much appreciated.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    
<body style="font-size: 2em; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
    <div style="column-count: 2;width: 50%;margin: 0 auto; vertical-align: middle;">
        <ul>
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
    
</html>
```

Comment: Move `column-count: 2;` to the `<ul>` element

Comment: That did the correction - thank you Zohi Salak, I appreciate your prompt help. Could you please your comment to an answer type? That way I can mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because of the browser's default `margin-block-start` and `margin-block-end` styling on the `<ul>` element. If you set those to `0` the list items will align perfectly:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    
<body style="font-size: 2em; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
    <div style="column-count: 2;width: 50%;margin: 0 auto; vertical-align: middle;">
        <ul style="margin: 0">
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
    
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. Please note that @Zohir Salak's comment also achieves the same. Do you think both are equivalently good solutions? If not please explain why.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out. The decoration of the ul li items will be changed but your task will be done. May be helpful:)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    
<body>
    <div class="Navbar">
        <ul>
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    
    <style>
        body{ font-size: 2em; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
        .Navbar ul li { display: inline-block; }
    </style>
    
</body>
    
</html>
```

Comment: Muditha - I appreciate you trying to help but this solution adds more items from left to right like this sentence growing from left to right. Try adding more items to your solution and watch what happens. You may try the two solutions provided before you.

Thank You